# Magento - get a list of bundled product ids from a product id

Tags: magento, bundle, product

Lets say I load my product object:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Is there a function or some way to extract the bundled ids related to this product?

e.g.

```
$product->getBundledProductIDs()
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$product->getTypeInstance(true)->getChildrenIds($product->getId(), false)
```

The result is a multi-dimensional array with the top level being options and the children of options being products.

Also, you can change the *false* to a *true* and it will only return required options of the bundle.

Comment: Lee you are my hero today!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this-

```
$collection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
    ->getSelectionsCollection(
        $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getOptionsIds($product), $product);

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    # $item->product_id has the product id.
}
```