# Magento - get bundled products where a simple product belongs to

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to show all bundles on a simple product's page and so need to retrieve the information. I searched and tried a lot. This post sounds promising, but is either not working or maybe not for my problem: 
[Magento - get a list of bundled product ids from a product id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255962/magento-get-a-list-of-bundled-product-ids-from-a-product-id?answertab=active#tab-top)

I found a solution for grouped products but this can't be applied here.

```
$grouped_product_model = Mage::getModel('bundle/product_selection');
$groupedParentId = $grouped_product_model->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
```

I found the table catalog_product_bundle_selection to be the right place to search, but I wonder if there is a clean way and existing function to search this table by product_id than just to hack this.

I didn't find a solution in Mage_Bundle.

What did I miss?

After getting first aid from vrnet I wrote a new block class, so I can update the layout

```
class Thomaier_Catalog_Block_Product_View_BundledSelect extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View 
{

    protected $_simpleProducts = array( '3' ); // just an example

    public function getBundles() {

        $bundleIds = array();

        $bundlesCollectionModel = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection');
        $bundlesCollection = $bundlesCollectionModel->getSelect()
             ->where('`selection`.`product_id` in (' . join(',', (array)$this->_simpleProducts) . ')');

        foreach ($bundlesCollection as $bundleItem) {
            $bundleIds[] = $bundleItem->getParentProductId();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

I skipped some parts. As I mentioned in the comment, the SQL query works fine when I try it in phpmyadmin, but $bundleItem is not created and ->load() throws an exception.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a method I wrote for a client having the same request with an extra : the ability to shuffle the result.

Hope it helps.

```
     protected $_simpleProducts = array(); // Array with IDs of simple products you want bundles from.

     protected $_shuffle = false;

    public function getBundles() {
        $bundleIds = array();

        /*Rather than using a collection model 
and make operations with getSelect,
a more elegant way is to extend
Mage_Bundle_Model_Mysql4_Selection_Collection
with a method that would be something like
setProductIdsFilter($productIds)*/

        $bundlesCollectionModel = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection');
        $bundlesCollection = $bundleCollectionModel->getSelect()
                                         ->where('`selection`.`product_id` in (' . join(',', (array)$this->_simpleProducts) . ')');
        foreach ($bundlesCollection as $bundleItem) {
            $bundleIds[] = $bundleItem->getParentProductId();
        }
        if (count($bundleIds)) {
            $allowBundles = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                            ->addIdFilter($bundleIds)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
            if ($this->_shuffle) {
                $allowBundles->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            }
            if ($allowBundles->count()) {
                return $allowBundles;
            }
        }
        return;
```

Comment: THANK YOUR for sharing your solution. This looks like solving my problem. Too bad, there is no existing method for this task.

Comment: Happy this has been helpful. And if you become a regular user of StackOverflow please feel free to come back here and +1 my answer :)

Comment: I implemented it as a new block into Catalog Module. The SQL is created successfully, but the foreach loop is not working. After some research it seems that something like "load()" is missing, but if I implement it, I get an error. What did I miss?

Comment: The load() method is not mandatory for a collection if you loop on it. The load() method will be automatically triggered by underlying Varien methods on "foreach". Can you please update your original question with the code of your block ?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the best way to work with these. This way you do not rely on a custom query but instead you can use the core methods:

```
$bundlesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection')
                             ->getParentIdsByChild($simple_product_ids_array_or_int);
        foreach ($bundlesCollection as $bundleProdId) {
              //do anything you want with the bundleProdId array elements
        }
```