# Magento - get list all bundled products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, bundle, product

I am using magento version 1.7.

I want show the all the bundled products in view.phtml file.

I get list of produts within bundle products using below link.

[Magento - get a list of bundled product ids from a product id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255962/magento-get-a-list-of-bundled-product-ids-from-a-product-id)

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);   

 $totl =  $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getChildrenIds($product->getId(), false);
```

how can i show all bundled products

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter the product collection by type:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('type')
    //->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'bundle') // simpler..
    ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'bundle')) // simple/configurable etc
;
```